# PHPUnit not recognizing cURL extension -- can't install selenium test

Tags: curl, selenium, phpunit, wamp, pear

I'm on a Windows 7 machine running a WAMPserver and I'm trying to install the Selenium extension for PEAR.  However, whenever I try to install it, I'm told that it requires the already-enabled PHP extension "curl":

`pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium`

```
Package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit" has no releases
phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium requires PHP extension "curl"
No valid packages found
install failed
```

So I go to check my php.ini file to see if it's enabled.  Sure enough, there it is:

```
extension=php_apc.dll
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
```

On [this website](http://kaalaya.blogspot.com/2010/03/php-phpunit-selenium-and-netbeans-ide.html), I was told to try this:

> 1. If you are getting an error as “No valid packages found Install failed” then run the following command   pear upgrade-all

But when I run that command, it just tells me `Nothing to upgrade-all`.

After searching for my specific error, I found a [PHP bug that mentions](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59028)

> The "curl" php extension needs to be loaded into php itself as an
>   extension.
>
> run this command
>
> php -me
>
> If "curl" is not listed as one of the [PHP Modules] it is not going to
>   work.

And I'm not entirely sure how to load this "into php itself as an extension" on Windows.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Or to get PEAR to believe that I *do* have this installed?

**EDIT**

For the record, my curl extension *is* noticed by PHP (from php_info()):

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.20.0
```

Comment: can you do a `php --ini | grep curl` to rule out an php.ini webserver vs. cli issue?

Comment: @edorian Running that command returned nothing.  There is no mention of curl when I run `php --ini` (nor any other extension).

Comment: @edorian -- no worries!  `php --ini` tells me `Loaded Configuration File: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini` which is the php.ini file I mention above that includes the php_curl.dll extension.

Comment: So `php -i` shows you the curl extension too? Strange. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: @edorian `php -i` actually *does not* show the curl extension.  Error_reporting is turned on.  What *does* show the curl extension, though, is the `php_info()` function as called from the root of my web directory.

Comment: That's why I'm suspecting some sort of web vs. cli configuration issue. Maybe that gets you somewhere :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most cases I'd say that this comes from a php configuration issue.

The easiest way to check for this is to use `php -i` and see if the curl extension shows up in the output. If it doesn't there is something wrong with the command line php. Chances are it's using the wrong `php.ini` file. `php --ini` can be used to check this

---

#### But there might be a case where one doesn't want to or can't enable the curl extension for some reason so I'll take that as an answer:

If **you** don't **need** the selenium module for phpunit there is a way of skipping the install of this package as it is an optional dependency.

```
pear install --onlyreqdeps phpunit/phpunit
```

should not install Selenium.

And just in case there is always one thing to try:

```
pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit
```

---

#### To tell pear to note care about the curl extension not being recognised there is:

```
pear install --force phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

which might work if there is some issue that just pear is not picking the extension up but normal scripts are.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to specifically install the selenium extension and already have PHPUnit itself installed.

Comment: Maybe using --force to just install it and see if it works then does the trick for you?

Comment: Forcing the install worked just fine.  Thanks for all the help! :D

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem on Ubuntu, and I solved it by running the following command,

sudo apt-get install php5-curl

Apparently there are two different curl packages (curl and php5-curl), the php5-curl one is for php.

Hope this could help

Answer (score 1):

While working on WAMP there are two php.ini files

1. Under Apache
2. Under Php

Make sure you have uncommented `"extension=php_curl.dll"` in both files. You're good after editing both files and restarting your wamp server. The pear installer might be looking for the curl settings in the PHP path even though your wamp server is using the Apache version.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be changes made to two php.ini in different locations, for example:

1. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8
2. C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin

Starting about line 950 you will see

```
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
; 
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
...
```

Change the ";extension=php_curl.dll" to "extension=php_curl.dll"

Restart your server and you should be ready to go.

Comment: My issue seemed to ultimately be with Pear, not with the ini files.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  edorian's answer was what got me there:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8496478/390977

Answer (score 0):

when you change php.ini from wamp server even from php menu, it changes the apache version and it dose not effect the php at all. I changed them from file system and it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I followed these answer above and I changed these files and is working correctly.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin
```