# Fatal error running unit test in Yii app

Tags: yii, phpunit, wamp

**This Question** is local to my situation and not resolved (yet).  But if you are experiencing this problem, the trouble shooting steps may give you a good path to start on.

---

I want to run a unit test in a Yii web application on localhost, which is running via WampServer 2.1 on Windows 7.

```
<?php
class LittleTest extends CTestCase
{
    public function testApprove()
    {
        $value1 = "1";
        $this->assertEquals($value1,$value1);
    }
}
?>
```

I receive a fatal error when I try to run the test.  Here is how I run it, on the Windows command line:

```
C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests>
C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests>cd unit
C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests\unit>phpunit LittleTest.php
```

I receive (along with some stack trace lines):

```
PHP Fatal error:  
class 'CTestCase' not found in [path to file]\LittleTest.php on line 4
```

**Trouble shooting steps to this point:**

The app runs.  The default index page of the app looks good and I have used the gii tool to create a model class.

From command line, I can see `php` and `phpunit` are available (and I've been over my pear install to make sure it's all good):

```
C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests>
C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests>phpunit --version
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests>
C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests>php --version
PHP 5.3.5 (cli) 
... etc
```

`display_errors` is turned on.  `display_startup_errors` is turned on.

I tried renaming the class so that name did not match the document name:

```
class LittleTestTweak extends CTestCase
```

I'm not sure of the precise command that runs the test, so I have tried variants like:

`php LittleTest.php`

Also I've tried running it various places in the folder structure.  Here is the immediate structure:

```
/tests
    |   bootstrap.php
    |   my_tree.txt
    |   phpunit.xml
    |   WebTestCase.php
    |   
    |---- /fixtures
    |---- /functional
    |         SiteTest.php
    |       
    |---- /report
    `---- /unit
              LittleTest.php
```

I also checked my `php.ini` for the path to PEAR; as far as I can tell, it's correct (but how can I test it?):

```
include_path=".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR;C:\wamp\www\app
```

### More Info

In response to this:

```
cd wamp\www\app\protected\tests
phpunit unit\LittleTest.php
```

I receive this:

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php): 
            failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
            C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CWebTestCase.php on line 12

Call Stack:
        0.0007     339624   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\phpunit:0
        0.0164     698440   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() 
               C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\phpunit:46
        0.0164     698856   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() 
               C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
        0.0164     698856   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() 
               C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:138
        0.0289    1220944   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() 
               C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:606
        0.0300    1233328   6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() 
               C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:778
        0.0330    1233424   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() 
               C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php:76
        0.0334    1238096   8. include_once
               ('C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests\bootstrap.php') 
               C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php:92
        0.0412    1520256   9. require_once
               ('C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests\WebTestCase.php') 
               C:\wamp\www\app\protected\tests\bootstrap.php:8
        0.0413    1520520  10. YiiBase::autoload() 
               C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\YiiBase.php:0
        0.0423    1543904  11. 
               include('C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CWebTestCase.php') 
               C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\YiiBase.php:395

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required     
        'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php' 
        (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\pear;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\pear') 
        in C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CWebTestCase.php on line 12

Call Stack:
    0.0007     339624   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\phpunit:0
    0.0164     698440   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()  
            ...et cetera...
```

The failed requirement is `PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php`.  I wonder if the issue is that PHPUnit is installed locally under `C:\wamp`.

I opened my `php.ini` and added to `include_path`:  `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions`.  Restarted wamp.  No change in error reporting.

### RESOLUTION

<strike>My security setup uses DansGuardian and I had neglected to loosen the settings for banned extension types, which blocks file downloads.  In fact I don't care to ban any types, and modifying that file allows everything to work.</strike> Woops, that's my Linux set.  PHPUnit is working there, and it is working on WAMP also.  Recreating the steps on WAMP is impossible; but I do know I had to [open cmd.exe as administrator](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-with-administrator-privileges-in-windows-vista/) and `pear update-channels`, `pear upgrade-all`, etc.  I also had to [clear pear's cache](http://www.mark-leong.com/installing-php-and-phpunit-on-windows-7/) at one point, and I had to [overcome an issue with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496478/122139) recognition to install Selenium:

```
pear install --force phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

Comment: can you paste the exact error message?

Comment: Unfortunately this windows command window won't let me copy to clipboard.  But hold on, I will try. .. OKAY, DONE

Comment: try from within _protected\tests_ directory: `phpunit unit/LittleTest.php`

Comment: I tried and received a lot of error reporting, suggesting my config is wrong.  Unfortunately I have to leave this project for a few hours right now, but I will get back as soon as I can.

Comment: ok, do add the new errors to the question

Comment: Please answer the question yourself, if you found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run unit tests in Yii with phpunit, you'll need to let phpunit load the *protected/tests/bootstrap.php* file which basically sets up a configuration, and autoloads the required classes (mainly pertaining to testing). The *bootstrap.php* file loads *[yiit.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/yiit.php)* which actually autoloads the required classes.

Now we can load all this configuration either by command line options when running phpunit, or let the configuration be read automatically through the *protected/tests/phpunit.xml* file.

For the latter method, the directory from where phpunit is invoked should have the *phpunit.xml* file in it, and in Yii default webapp, this directory is *protected/tests*. Therefore you need to do the following to run your tests:

```
cd wamp\www\app\protected\tests
phpunit unit\LittleTest.php
```

Comment: Yes, thanks to post linked below I was aware of need for the XML config file.  However, no success -- see brutal large paste with my OP.  
http://stackoverflow.com/q/12760644/122139

Comment: well it just seems that your phpunit installation is a little messed up. I don't have a windows system, where I can test things and give you solid advice, sorry, but a few google searches revealed many similar problems. And most of them suggest re-installing phpunit using pear, check [yii-forum link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/16553-cant-get-phpunit-and-selenium-working-correctly/)

Comment: [another link from yii-forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/14995-wamp-netbeans-phpunit-selenium-yii/)

Comment: my pear install was messed up indeed, see new bottom-most addition to the OP.  Thanks again.

Comment: Not good enough, this is more a workaround than solving the root cause of the issue

Comment: @surfer190 there were 2 things which went wrong for smandoli, 1. running the test case with proper initialization (which my answer covers), 2. wrongly setup/installed phpunit, which the previous comments to this answer cover. so i think the answer is fine as is for this question. but of course you are entitled to your views.